# Convexity of $ t \mapsto \log \left[ \int_0^1 f^{pt} g^{q(1-t)} dx \right] $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g \geq 0$ be bounded, measurable functions on $[0,1].$ For real $p,q>0$ with $p^{-1}+q^{-1} = 1$, I want to show the convexity of

$$ h(t) = \log \left[ \int_0^1 f^{pt} g^{q(1-t)} dx \right].$$

If we consider $\lambda \in (0,1)$, then we can find

$$ h(\lambda t + (1-\lambda)s) = \log \left[\int_0^1 \left(f^{pt}g^{q(1-t)} \right)^\lambda \left( f^{ps}g^{q(1-s)} \right)^{1-\lambda} dx \right], $$

which looks like it might be useful, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $k=\frac{1}{\lambda} , m=\frac{1}{1-\lambda}$ then $k^{-1} +m^{-1} =\lambda +(1-\lambda )=1$ so by Holder inequality we get $$e^{h(\lambda t + (1-\lambda)s)} = \int_0^1 \left(f^{pt}g^{q(1-t)} \right)^\lambda \left( f^{ps}g^{q(1-s)} \right)^{1-\lambda} dx \leq \left(\int_0^1 \left(f^{pt}g^{q(1-t)} \right)^{\lambda \cdot k} dx\right)^\frac{1}{k} \cdot \left(\int_0^1 \left( f^{ps}g^{q(1-s)} \right)^{(1-\lambda)\cdot m} dx\right)^\frac{1}{m} = \left(\int_0^1 f^{pt}g^{q(1-t)}  dx\right)^\lambda \cdot \left(\int_0^1  f^{ps}g^{q(1-s)}  dx\right)^{1-\lambda} =e^{\lambda h(t) +(1-\lambda )h(s)}$$ hence $$h(\lambda t +(1-\lambda) s)\leq \lambda h(t) +(1-\lambda )h(s).$$

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are fixed.

Comment: I have just edited. Now should be ok.

Comment: I was able to come up with this as well,  but it bothers me that the assumptions on $p$ and $q$ aren't used. But I also can't see why they are needed.

Comment: These assumptions are for decoration. It plays a role when $f,g$ are not bounded and $f\in L_p $ and $g\in L_q$.